# Dependencies from build.gradle are not imported

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, temporal-workflow

I am trying import the Java SDK for Temporal ([www.temporal.io](http://www.temporal.io)). I follow just the first few lines of their [quick start guide](https://docs.temporal.io/docs/java-quick-start). It is a Spring Boot application that is generated with the Spring Initializr. My build.gradle looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.cardlay.temporaldemo'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    //Java Temporal SDK
    implementation group: 'io.temporal', name: 'temporal-sdk', version: '1.0.7'
    implementation group: 'commons-configuration', name: 'commons-configuration', version: '1.10'
    implementation group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.2.3'

    // Spring Boot Application dependencies
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'

    // Testing dependencies
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

The weird thing is, however, that if I make an application **without** Spring Boot, then Gradle will recognize temporal and allow me to do imports in my classes.

So what is it about the Spring Boot `build.gradle` file and configuration, that doesn't allow me to do imports?

Comment: Did you reimport/refresh the projecet after adding that dependency?

Comment: @M.Deinum I clicked "Reload all Gradle projects" and wrote `./gradlew build`

Comment: Is it possible to download/clone the SDK and then include it as a reference in my project somehow, since there are no answers and the above doesn't work?

Comment: People here are answering in their own time, you asked this question an hour ago. If you want commercial support invest money. It should just work like another java project, as it is just a java project. So there must be something in your setup you aren't sharing that is messing this up.

Comment: @M.Deinum I think you misinterpret my comment - "since there are no answers" was more of a testament to that the problem is not obvious/something seems to be wrong with my setup besides `build.gradle` somehow and if I should try another approach.

Comment: Trying another approach would make it work in the IDE and next fail in regular build so it won't solve a thing. Which IDE are you using?

Comment: Okay, I can see that. I am using IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Most recent version by chance? If so try downgrading to 2020.3 instead of using 2021.1.

Comment: I am actually using 2020.3  - Community Edition - already. I appreciate the suggestion though.

Comment: I've been trying that file, works for me. So it must be something on your side, make sure that you don't use a too new JDK as gradle won't support that, and that you have set Intellij to use the gradle wrapper instead of locally installed gradle.

Comment: @M.Deinum Okay, that confirms that it is on my part. I will try to downgrade JDK and use gradle wrapper instead. Thank you for the help and suggestions how I can proceed, I appreciate your time. :)